Mock Location Flutter
How to create or develop a mock location using flutter framework what should i need to know? Is there any plugins already exist which will give me a random location or fake gps? I searched i find some mock location detector which will detect my locations not providing them.
I want to build an food delivery app which will alows me to show location but not the current location,I need fake location or gps.
For this, should i get help from third party sites to get fake gps or is there any existing plugins which will provide me fake location or gps

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
